# Separating values from text file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read in a text file with the following data:

```
 362  147
 422   32
 145   45
 312   57
  35  421
 361  275
```

and I want to separate the values into pairs so 362 and 147 would be pair 1, 422 and 32 pair 2 and so on.

However I run into a problem during the 5 pair which should be 35,421 but for some reason my code does not split this pair correctly, i think this is because of the spaces since only this pair has a two digit number and then a 3 digit number. But I'm not sure how to fix this, here's my code:

```
def __init__(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r") #reads file
    #print (f.read) # test if file was actually read 
    f1 = f.readlines() # reads individual lines
    counter = 0
    for line in f1: 
        values = line.split("  ") #splits the two values for each line into an array
        value1 = values[0].strip() #.strip removes spaces at each values
        value2 = values[1].strip()
        counter = counter + 1
        print('\npair: {}'.format(counter))
        #print(values)
        print(value1)
        print(value2)
```

The output I get:

```
pair: 1
362
147

pair: 2
422
32

pair: 3
145
45

pair: 4
312
57

pair: 5

35

pair: 6
361
275
```

Comment: Try calling just split() without arguments

Comment: Change `values = line.split("  ")` to `values = line.strip().split()`

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think it was gonna be such a simple fix, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def __init__(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lines = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
        for line_num, line in enumerate(lines):
            p1, p2 = [i for i in line.split() if i]
            print(f"pair: {line_num+1}\n{p1}\n{p2}\n\n")
```

**Note** : Always try to use `with open()`. In this way python takes care of closing the file automatically at the end.

The problem with your code is that you're not checking whether the words extracted after splitting `values` are empty string or not. If you print `values` for each line, for the pair 5, you'ld notice it is `['', '35', '421\n']`. The first value of this one is an empty string. You can change your code to this :

```
def __init__(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r") #reads file
    #print (f.read) # test if file was actually read 
    f1 = f.readlines() # reads individual lines
    counter = 0
    for line in f1: 
        values = line.split() #splits the two values for each line into an array; Addendum .split(" ") is equivalent to .split()
        values = [i for i in values if i] #Removes the empty strings
        value1 = values[0].strip() #.strip removes spaces at each values
        value2 = values[1].strip()
        counter = counter + 1
        print('\npair: {}'.format(counter))
        #print(values)
        print(value1)
        print(value2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
values = line.split("  ")
```

to:

```
values = line.split()
```